# Validity of multiindex inequality $|x^\alpha|\le |x|^{|\alpha|}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The standard (I think) proof that harmonic functions are real-analytic (c.f. Evans' PDE book (2nd ed.), pp. 31-32, or McOwen's PDE book (2nd ed.), p. 124) seems to use the estimate $|x^\alpha|\le |x|^{|\alpha|}$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ is a multiindex.  However, I don't think this estimate is true!  In fact, it fails for the first thing I tried: take $n=2$, $x = (0.3, 0.4)$, and $\alpha = (2,1)$. Then $|x^\alpha| = |(0.09,0.4)| = \sqrt{0.1681}=0.41$, while $|x|^{|\alpha|} = 0.5^3 = 0.125$. Am I missing something--is there something silly wrong with my counterexample? Alternatively, (for anyone who has access to either of the books I mention above:) is this estimate actually used in the proof of real analyticity, or does the proof actually depend on some other estimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not computing $x^\alpha$ correctly.  Usually, $x^\alpha$ means $x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ (i.e., the product).

In your example, $x^\alpha$ means $0.3^2\cdot 0.4^1=0.036<0.125$.  The $|\cdot|$ in $|x^\alpha|$ are absolute bars, not norm bars.  On the other hand, the $|\cdot|$ in $|x|^{|\alpha|}$ are norm bars.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.  Sorry for the silly question.